# Not able to upload Pfx certifcate to Azure key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

Team,

Whenever I try to upload a pfx certificate to azure key vault via the steps mentioned here

```
$securepfxpwd = ConvertTo-SecureString –String 'password' –AsPlainText –Force # Password for the private key PFX certificate 
$certificateName = 'My-Cert' 
$vaultName = 'MyVault' 
$cer = Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $vaultName -Name $certificateName -FilePath 'C:\My-Cert.pfx' -Password $securepfxpwd
```

I get this error

> Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate : Unsupported key size (1024).
>   Supported sizes are [2048, 3072, 4096] At line:1 char:8
>   + $cer = Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $vaultName -Name $c ...
>   +        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Import-AzureKeyVaultCertificate], KeyVaultErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.ImportAzureKeyVaultCertificate

How do I possibly upload a pfx of size less than 2048 a specified or is it that keyvault only accepts sizes mentioned in the square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the certificate as a secret instead of a certificate.

e.g. https://gist.github.com/bmoore-msft/425b79b7b7e226264554ec534b956a48

Comment: thanks alex. Seems to be an answer. However I have an exisiting pfx certificate on my cdrive. Is there any way I can change the code? its asking for self signed certificate.